# Is there a way to print the individual steps of the test cases in extentreport

Tags: extentreports

Is there a way to print the test steps in the extent report? 
Example for login test case, I want to print

1.username entered
2. password entered
3. login button clicked

Maybe if after status, timestamp and details, steps can be added

Answer (score 0):

I'm using ExtentReport in Framework like below code and I very satisfied with that. Hope, below sample code, works for you

```
// initialize the HtmlReporter
public ExtentHtmlReporter htmlReporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter("C:\\report\\path\\to\\report.html");
// initialize the report
public ExtentReports report  = new ExtentReports();
// initialize the report
public ExtentTest logger ;
//ExtentHtmlReporter and ExtentXReporter allow appending test information to an existing report.
htmlReporter.setAppendExisting(true);
// attach only HtmlReporter
report.attachReporter(htmlReporter);

//Create main test cases
logger = report.createTest("Driver Initialization");

logger.log(Status.INFO, "Starting firefox browser");
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "path\\to\\geckodriver\\geckodriver.exe");
driver = new FirefoxDriver();
logger.log(Status.INFO, "Browser started");

driver.get("www.facebook.com");
logger.log(Status.INFO, "Title is: "+driver.getTitle());

logger.log.(Status.PASS, "Application opened");

driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("validuser");
logger.log(Status.INFO, "username entered");

driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("validpassword");
logger.log(Status.INFO, "Password entered");

driver.findElement(By.id("login")).click();
logger.log(Status.INFO, "login button clicked");

logger.log(Status.PASS, "Home page opened");

//Simply call the flush() method to write or update test information to your reporter. 
report.flush();

driver.quite();
```

Let me know if you any query.